# Setting up a (Windows) Hadoop cluster

Tags: windows, hadoop, cluster-computing

I have installed Hadoop-0.20.2 on my machine (Windows). I tried setting up clustering of nodes, with a master and a slave. But I am unable to connect the machines. There is a password authentication error.

How can this be addressed? If it is possible, please provide me a suitable link for setting up multiple clusters in Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-node Windows Cluster, the Hortonworks website has an installation document here:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0-Win/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-install-chap2-3.html

These are the instructions for a single node cluster on Windows Server 2012 (HDP 2.0 for Windows): http://hortonworks.com/blog/install-hadoop-windows-hortonworks-data-platform-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

password authentication error means, Is it the firewall, AD etc. Specify the windows version and your network details.

I followed this link http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/ to set up the Hadoop on our windows server.